# HTTP Error 307: Temporary Redirect in Python3 - INTRANET

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, urllib

The code generates a series of URLs and searches them for a specific string.
As the website requires login information:

- I logged in the website through my browsers.
- And for more checks, I tried only one complete URL(of the same website) with no values and encoding and it worked perfectly well. So I supposed the login information shouldn't be the problem.
- I did try to add log-in info through the code, but as it itself brought up a series of errors, I wanted to see if that is really necessary to work on. Maybe there is another solution with no need to log-in.
- Lately, I understood the link is in "intranet" not "internet". Can that be the problem?

This is the code:

```
         url ='https://www.aug.ipp.mpg.de/cgibin/sfread_only/isis?'

    shotn = shot_a
    #Shot_a, shot_z, diag and param are user inputs.
    enter code here
    while (shotn <= shot_z):
        values = {'shot': shotn,
                  'exp': 'AUGD',
                  'diag': diag ,
                  'action': 'SignalDetails',
                  'signal': param}



       data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
       #The upper line is line 42- the first error
        respData = resp.read()
       shotn +=1
```

The expected result would be a `.txt` file in the computer which includes the `shotn's` which that specific statement was found in the corresponding URL.

---

And this is actual result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/PycharmProjects/ url/venv/Final.py", line 42, in <module>
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 734, in http_error_302
    new = self.redirect_request(req, fp, code, msg, headers, newurl)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 672, in redirect_request
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, headers, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 307: Temporary Redirect

Process finished with exit code 1
```